# Como pausar Thread enquanto Alert executa dentro do Platform.runLater - JavaFX Java

Tags: java, thread, javafx, dialog, alert

Preciso executar um método dentro de um Thread que contém Alert e Dialog. Como já sabem o JavaFX possui a limitação de não conseguir mostrar o Alert ou Dialog dentro de um Thread, então eu coloco eles dentro de um Platform.runLater e funciona, o problema é que enquanto o Alert é exibido a Thread segue seu fluxo. **Gostaria que o comportamento fosse igual quando não se usa Thread, fazendo com o que fluxo fosse pausado enquanto o Alert não for fechado. Poderiam por gentileza me ajudar ?**
   Abaixo trecho do código de exemplo:

```
// Processa conteudo dentro da Task
public static void testeThread()
{
    Runnable task = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
                System.out.println("inciando Thread, executa tarefas ");

                // *** Tratamento para alert/Dialog
                Platform.runLater(()-> 
                {
                    //Exibe mensagem ao usuario sobre bloqueio
                Alert alertLicencaInvalida = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
                alertLicencaInvalida.setTitle("Erro");
                alertLicencaInvalida.setHeaderText("Erro");
                alertLicencaInvalida.setContentText(" Ocorreu ");
                alertLicencaInvalida.showAndWait();
                // enquanto estiver aqui dentro, Thread deve ficar aguardando
                });
                // continuar Thread apos Alert for fechado
                System.out.println("Continuando Thread ");
            }
    };
    // Run the task in a background thread
    Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(task);
    // Terminate the running thread if the application exits
    backgroundThread.setDaemon(true);
    // Start the thread
    backgroundThread.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução, tirada [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14941084/2241463), é pausar a thread usando os recursos de comunicação entre threads do Java, no caso `FutureTask`:

```
System.out.println("inciando Thread, executa tarefas ");
String proximoTexto = lerDadosDeAlgumLugar();

if ("PROBLEMA".equals(proximoTexto)) {
    FutureTask<String> futureTask = new FutureTask(new AlertaDeErro());
    Platform.runLater(futureTask);
    proximoTexto = futureTask.get(); // vai pausar neste ponto
}

System.out.println("Continuando a thread...");
```

**AlertaDeErro.java**

```
class AlertaDeErro implements Callable<String> {
    private TextField textField;

    @Override public String call() throws Exception {
        //Exibe mensagem ao usuario sobre bloqueio
        Alert alertLicencaInvalida = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
        alertLicencaInvalida.setTitle("Erro");
        alertLicencaInvalida.setHeaderText("Erro");
        alertLicencaInvalida.setContentText(" Ocorreu ");
        alertLicencaInvalida.showAndWait();
        return "Se eu quiser retornar alguma coisa para o thread, retorno aqui";
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @Piovezan sua explicaçao me ajudou muito. Eu já havia encontrado o código que você mencionou na resposta, mas não tinha conseguido aplicar em meu projeto.

Answer (score 0):

Com base na explicação @Piovezan, consegui aplicar a solução em meu código. Segue classe completa para ajudar futuros programadores:

```
    public class teste2 extends Application 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception 
    {
        testeThread();
    }
    public static void testeThread()
    {
        Runnable task = new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    System.out.println("inciando Thread, executa tarefas ");
                    boolean retornoAlert;
                    class AlertaDeErro implements Callable<Boolean>
                    {
                        @Override
                        public Boolean call() throws Exception
                        {
                            // Exibe mensagem ao usuario sobre bloqueio
                            Alert alertLicencaInvalida = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
                            alertLicencaInvalida.setTitle("Erro");
                            alertLicencaInvalida.setHeaderText("Erro");
                            alertLicencaInvalida.setContentText(" Ocorreu... ");
                            alertLicencaInvalida.showAndWait();
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    FutureTask<Boolean> futureTask = new FutureTask(new AlertaDeErro());
                    Platform.runLater(futureTask);
                    retornoAlert = futureTask.get(); // Para processamento da Thread e recebe retorno

                    // continuar Thread apos Alert for fechado
                    System.out.println("Continuando Thread "+ retornoAlert);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(teste2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(teste2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        };
        // inicia Thread
        Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(task);
        backgroundThread.setDaemon(true);
        backgroundThread.start();
    }
}
```